# How to get instagram data for public profiles (without token) post-API shutdown?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Most of the users on our platform are high end profiles (athletes). We have managed to authenticate in many of them and we can get their data (posts, # of followers, # of likes/comments). But many haven't authenticated in but we still need their data (They have public profiles) .

I have tried the "__a=1" but that also seems to have some limits (doesn't get videos, limited and gets blocked after a while, and needs an Instagram login, which makes it difficult to get it from our code).

```
https://instagram.com/username/?__a=1
```

I am thinking out scraping but it would be really difficult I suppose (and I haven't done it before).

Has anyone found a solution to retrieve data for public instagram accounts? How can I implement my own scraping - any ideas how to do it?